# How does the JavaScript Canvas globalAlpha Property work?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a fade out effect with JavaScript on the Canvas element. I'm currently have two sollutions for this. In theory, both should work fine, but in practice, only one does, and I wonder why.

**The not working code is the following:**

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var i = 1;
requestAnimationFrame(test);

function test(){
 i-=0.01;
 ctx.fillStyle = "white";
 ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
 ctx.globalAlpha = i;
 ctx.fillStyle = "red";
 ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
 requestAnimationFrame(test);
}
```

What I wanted to achieve, is to gradually change the alpha value of the current context, in order to fade it to white. After a while, it should have full transparency, but it does not. It stops right before reaching that state. Here it is in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bq75v1mm/

**The working code is the following:**

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var i = 1;
requestAnimationFrame(test);
function test(){
 i-=0.01;
 ctx.fillStyle = "white";
 ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
 ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+255+","+0+","+0+","+i+")";
 ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
 requestAnimationFrame(test);
}
```

With this code, I'm just simply changing the alpha value of the given fillStyle for the upcoming rectangle, and it works like a charm, and makes the square vanish into thin air. Here it is in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mxtynwwd/

I would like to understand why doesn't the first sollution work? Why can't I lower the globalAlpha value after a given minimum? Or is the problem in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In your second example, you reset `fillStyle` every time before drawing the white rectangle.
   You're not doing the same with `globalAlpha` in your first example.
2. Not all values will be accepted by the `globalAlpha` property. Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha):

   > A number between `0.0` (fully transparent) and `1.0` (fully opaque). The default value is `1.0` Values outside the range, including `Infinity` and `NaN` will not be set and `globalAlpha` will retain its previous value.

   Due to precision loss in floating pointer math, when `i` becomes negative, `globalAlpha` gets stuck on `0.009999999999999247` (may vary across machines).

To fix both of the above, reset `globalAlpha` before drawing the white rectangle:

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
```

and before drawing the red one, make sure `i` is `>= 0`:

```
i = i < 0 ? 0 : i;
```

Your first example can accordingly be updated to behave exactly like your second one:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var i = 1;
requestAnimationFrame(test);

function test() {
    i -= 0.01;
    i = i < 0 ? 0 : i;
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
    ctx.globalAlpha = i;
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
    requestAnimationFrame(test);
}
```

**[ [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bq75v1mm/1/) ]**